# Residual calculus

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I wish to construct a function $f(z)$ with the properties as

1. only singularities of $f(z)$ in the extended complex plane are poles of order of $1$ and $2$ at $z= 1$ and $z=-1$ respectively.
2. Also it is given that $f(0)= 0=f(-1/2)$ and residue of $f(z)$ at $z= 1$ and $z=-1$ is equal to $1$ .

Comment: What have you done?  Hint: Start with the poles.

Comment: Let f(z) = F(z) +P(z) where F(z) is the regular part & P(z) is the principal part which Is P(z) = 1/(z+1) + b/(z+1)^2 + 1/(z-1)....but I don't know how to proceed further to get the desired function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sketch:

- Write your function as a rational function.  This makes it easy to specify the poles and zeros (when you have finitely many).
- The information that $z=1$ is a pole of order 1 and $z=-1$ is a pole of order $2$ implies that your function appears as (where the $\cdots$ indicates that we have not filled in the numerator yet.
  $$
  \frac{\cdots}{(z-1)(z+1)^2}.
  $$
- Since $f(0)=0=f(-1/2)$, then the numerator includes the factors $z$ and $2z+1$.  In other words, our function is of the form (where the $\cdots$ indicates that we might have more to fill in).
  $$
  \frac{z(2z+1)\cdots}{(z-1)(z+1)^2}.
  $$
- Since the residue at $z=1$ is $1$, then substituting $z=1$ into 
  $$
  \frac{z(2z+1)\cdots}{(z+1)^2}
  $$
  should give you $1$.
- Since the residue at $z=-1$ is $1$, and this is a pole of order $2$, then substituting $z=-1$ into 
  $$
  \frac{d}{dz}\frac{z(2z+1)\cdots}{(z-1)}
  $$
  should also give you $1$.

(Check these last two formulas on your own.)

Now, all you need to do is to figure out *any* appropriate $\cdots$ that make the last two equations true. (and don't change the order of the poles).

---

Responding to comments:

- The last two conditions correspond to two equations, so we would expect to need two variables in the $\cdots$ to be able to simultaneously solve them.  Therefore, we would look at 
  $$
  \frac{z(2z+1)(az+b)}{(z-1)(z+1)^2}.
  $$
- Using this form to guess, the two equations become:
  $$
  \left.\frac{z(2z+1)(az+b)}{(z+1)^2}\right|_{z=1}=\frac{3(a+b)}{4}=1
  $$
  and
  $$
  \left.\frac{d}{dz}\right|_{z=-1}\frac{z(2z+1)(az+b)}{(z-1)}=\left.\frac{(z-1)((2z+1)(az+b)+2z(az+b)+az(2z+1))-z(2z+1)(az+b)}{(z-1)^2}\right|_{z=-1}=1.
  $$
  Then, solve for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I got  ur point ...but isn't complicated to find such function in the numerator which satisfies the last two equation simultaneously which yields its residue 1 even when they are tending to different limit one is 1 and the other is -1 ...plus in first part its simple to get the value of function in numerator. That's g(1)=4/3 ..but wat about the second part ...its differentiation dere ...m stucked! Sort it out plz

Comment: One more linear term is likely enough, you've got two equations and you need two unknowns.

Comment: Thumps up dude ! U have explained it very clearly ..thank-you so much :)